# Don't change string value on insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Model `user` with the following method:

```
  def number_with_hyphen
    number&.insert(8, "-")
  end
```

When I run it several times in my tests I get the following output:

```
users(:default).number_with_hyphen
"340909-1234"
(byebug) users(:default).number_with_hyphen
"340909--1234"
(byebug) users(:default).number_with_hyphen
"340909---1234"
(byebug) users(:default).number_with_hyphen
"340909----1234"
```

**It changes the `number` ?**Here are the docs https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/String/insert

When I restructure my method to:

```
  def number_with_hyphen
    "#{number}".insert(8, "-") if number
  end
```

If works like expected. The output stays the same!

**How would you structure the code, how would you perform the insert?** 
which method should I use instead. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [`insert`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-insert) method, which in the documentation explicitly states "modifies *str*", then you will need to avoid doing this twice, rendering it idempotent, or use another method that doesn't mangle data.

One way is a simple regular expression to extract the components you're interested in, ignoring any dash already present:

```
def number_with_hyphen
  if (m = number.match(/\A(\d{8})\-?(\d+)\z/))
    [ m[1], m[2] ].join('-')
  else
    number
  end
end
```

That ends up being really safe. If modified to accept an argument, you can test this:

```
number = '123456781234'

number_with_hyphen(number)
# => "12345678-1234"
number
# => "123456781234"
number_with_hyphen(number_with_hyphen(number))
# => "12345678-1234"
number_with_hyphen('1234')
# => "1234"
```

Calling it twice doesn't mangle anything, and any non-conforming data is sent through as-is.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Is there something similar to `insert` that does not modifies str? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to compose the string some other way, like `number[0,8] + '-' + number[8,number.length]` or something like that. You could also work on a copy, like `number.dup.insert(...)` which would have no effect on the original, but runs the risk of double-dashing if run twice for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clone of the string:

```
"#{number}".clone.insert(8, '-')
```

Comment: `"#{number}"` is enough as it creates a new `String` as the OP inadvertently pointed out

Comment: `"#{x}"` is a pattern I really wish people would drop. It's something that crawled out of the tar pit of `bash`. It's much better to say what you mean: `number.clone`.

Comment: @tadman agree, I just re-used the line on the OP's example, I usually just use string interpolation when formatting text really.